# Missing term in mapped-averaging derivation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

This question is really just trying to identify an error in my math, not about the method itself. **TLDR: I find Eq. 3, instead of the result given in the literature, Eq. 4. I'm trying to figure out where the missing term involving the divergence of $\vec{u}$ comes from.**

I am working through deriving the basic equation for the mapped-averaging method for reduced-variance sampling of thermodynamic properties in molecular simulation.[1][2] Essentially, this method extends the Free Energy Perturbation method
$$ e^{-\beta \Delta F} = \left\langle e^{-\beta\left(U_B(\vec{x}) - U_A(\vec{x})\right)}\right\rangle_A $$

by sampling a modified potential energy difference where the phase space coordinate $\vec{x}$ is mapped to a different coordinate $\vec{y}$ which reduces the variance of the integrand. The starting point for the mapped-averaging framework is the Targeted free energy perturbation equation

$$ e^{-\beta \left(F(\lambda ') - F(\lambda)\right)} = \left\langle J_\vec{y}(\vec{x}) e^{-\beta\left(U(\vec{y};\lambda') - U(\vec{x};\lambda)\right)} \right\rangle \;. \:\:(1)$$

Here, \lambda is a parameter which differentiates between states $A$ and $B$. Mapped-averaging uses this framework for differential changes in $\lambda$ to more efficiently sample free energy derivatives $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda}$. Following Endnote 10 in Ref [1], I substitute $\vec{y} = \vec{x} + \vec{u}\mathrm{d}\lambda$ and $\lambda' = \lambda + \mathrm{d}\lambda$ into Eq. [1] and expand both sides in terms of $\mathrm{d}\lambda$ about $\mathrm{d}\lambda=0$. For the expansion of Eq. 1 to first order in $\mathrm{d}\lambda$, the only terms that contain $\mathrm{d}\lambda$ are $e^{-\beta F(\lambda')}$ on the left and $e^{-\beta U(\vec{y};\lambda')}$ on the right. Expanding both of those in terms of $\mathrm{d}\lambda$ I find

$$ e^{\beta F(\lambda)} \left[ e^{-\beta F(\lambda)} - \beta\mathrm{d}\lambda\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda}\right)e^{-\beta F(\lambda)} + \mathcal{O}(\mathrm{d}\lambda^2) \right] = \left\langle J_\vec{y}(\vec{x})e^{\beta U(\vec{x};\lambda)} \left[ e^{-\beta U(\vec{x};\lambda)} - \beta\mathrm{d}\lambda e^{-\beta U(\vec{x};\lambda)} \left(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla U + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \lambda}\right)\right) + \mathcal{O}(\mathrm{d}\lambda^2)\right]\right\rangle \;. \;\;(2)$$

For $\vec{y} = \vec{x} + \vec{u}\mathrm{d}\lambda$, $J_\vec{y}(\vec{x})=1$ and Eq. 2 simplifies to give

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = \left\langle\vec{u}\cdot\nabla U\right\rangle + \left\langle \frac{\partial U}{\partial \lambda}\right\rangle \;.\:\:(3) $$

This differs from the result given in Ref. [1], which gives the result

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = \left\langle \frac{\partial U}{\partial \lambda} + \vec{u}\cdot\nabla U -kT\nabla\cdot\vec{u}\right\rangle \;. \:\: (4)$$

I can't identify where I'm missing the third term that includes the divergence of $\vec{u}$. Any help seeing where that term originates and where I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

[1](https://harvest.aps.org/v2/journals/articles/10.1103/PhysRevE.65.046122/fulltext) Jarzynski, *Targeted free energy perturbation*, Phys Rev E 65 (2002)

[2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.6b00018) Schultz, et. al, *Reformulation of Ensemble Averages via Coordinate Mapping*, JCTC 12 (2016)